# Keep radio button check after submit . PHP syntax error

Tags: php, syntax, while-loop, syntax-error

I have a PHP syntax error, but PHP doesn't tell me where it is ...
Maybe you could help me

I have a QCM and user need to clic on radio buttons to validate his choice.
But after the form has been submit, radio button are unckecked ...

```
<?php
    for ($i=1;$i<11;$i++) {
        echo '<input type="radio" name="radioq'.$i.'" value="'.$data_exercice['id'].'" '.if (isset($_POST['radioq'.$i]) && $_POST['radioq'.$i] == $data_exercice['id']) { echo 'checked="checked"';}.'/>';
    }
?>
```

Thank you

Comment: The answer has already been given but add these next time to your .htaccess to determine syntax errors.
    `php_flag display_startup_errors on`
    `php_flag display_errors on`
    `php_flag html_errors on`

Comment: Omg, I can't believe what I could write (this was the beginning...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put an if/else statement in an echo statement. Separate the two by setting the value of `$checked` before echoing out your HTML.

```
<?php
    $checked = (isset($_POST['radioq'.$i]) && $_POST['radioq'.$i] == $data_exercice['id']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '';
    echo '<input type="radio" name="radioq'.$i.'" value="'.$data_exercice['id'].'" '.$checked.'/>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to randomly insert an `if` statement within a string.  You would need to enclose it in parentheses and use a different form of if:

```
<?php
    for ($i=1;$i<11;$i++) {
        echo '<input type="radio" name="radioq'.$i.'" value="'.$data_exercice['id'].'" '.((isset($_POST['radioq'.$i]) && $_POST['radioq'.$i] == $data_exercice['id']) ? 'checked="checked"' : '').'/>';
    }
?>
```